# Why is my Flutter res/values/strings_en.arb file empty?

Tags: android, build, dart, flutter

While trying to build an APK using Android Studio the process fails with the following error message:

Error:

> Error:(1, -1) android-apt-compiler: [my_app]
>
> C:\Users\my_name\AndroidStudioProjects\my_app\res\values\strings_en.arb:1:
>
> error: Error parsing XML: no element found

I am assuming the strings_en.arb is supposed to have something in it, XML?

Can someone direct me in how to populate this file?

This is in a clean new project into which I have copy/pasted my correctly working Flutter/Dart files.  Basically created a new Flutter app and pasted my files into the proper Android Studio directories.